# CSS position absolute and full width problem

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want to change the `<dl id="site_nav_global_primary">` below to take up the full screen width without changing the wrap and the header elements containing it.

When I try to position the `<dl>` element (see the `/* problematic code */` section) below, the navigation gets the 100% of the wrapper which has a max width of 1003px. I want it to stretch to the maximum without changing the wrap and header divs.

```css
#wrap {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
    min-width:760px;
    max-width:1003px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: lightgray; /* for illustrative purposes */
}

#header {
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    padding-top:18px;
    margin-bottom:29px;
    background-color: rebeccapurple; /* for illustrative purposes */
}

#site_nav_global_primary {    
    float:right;
    margin-right:18px;
    margin-bottom:11px;
    margin-left:18px;
    background-color: salmon; /* for illustrative purposes */
}

/* Problematic code */
#site_nav_global_primary {    
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">
        <dl id="site_nav_global_primary">Lorem Ipsum</dl>
    </div>
<div>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why would you want it to be wider than it's container? For me, it seems like you should take the dl outside of the containing divs if you don't want it to be bound by their constraints.

Answer (score 303, accepted):

You could set both `left` and `right` property to `0`. This will make the div stretch to the document width, but requires that no parent element is positioned (which is not the case, seeing as `#header` is `position: relative;`)

```css
#site_nav_global_primary {    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/xWnq2/, where I removed `position:relative;` from `#header`

Comment: just a sidenote, left and right also accept negative values, see: http://jsfiddle.net/xWnq2/1/ but requires parents not to have overflow: hidden; - this won't let you easily make it stretch to "maximum" however

Comment: if you are looking for the width of the parent element then a mix of this as well as 2nd solution worked for me.

Answer (score 29):

You need to add `position:relative` to #wrap element.

When you add this, all child elements will be positioned in this element, not browser window.

Comment: tried it, doesn't work.. still getting the 100% of the max 1003px

Comment: @Tom any margin, padding, borders?

Comment: I have tried a mix of both the top solution to use left:0 , right:0, And parent position relative and was able to achieve the expected result

Comment: This work for me.

Answer (score 13):

I have similar situation. In my case, it doesn't have a parent with position:relative. Just paste my solution here for those that might need.

```css
position: fixed;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

Comment: This just repeats xec's accepted solution from 2011.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the following CSS to parent `div` worked for me

```
position: relative;
max-width: 100%
```

Comment: This appears to repeat Andrzej's solution from 2011.

Answer (score 1):

This one also works. With this method, there is no need to interfere with positioning of parent divs. I have checked

```
#site_nav_global_primary {    
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: This isn't the worst idea, `width: 100vw` will force the element to be as wide as the viewport. However, because of `overflow: hidden`, and the main content is centered - it won't get placed to the left edge of the document, but instead overflow to the right, and be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Make `#site_nav_global_primary` positioned as fixed and set width to 100 % and desired height.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if this what you want but try to remove overflow: hidden from #wrap

Comment: I copied your code, run i FX remove overflow from #wrap and it works