# Extend element beyond _Layout container MVC ASP.NET (preferred method?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing a little experimenting with MVC / Bootstrap / ASP.NET...

Specifically I'm trying to understand a best practice to allow an element to extend past its container based on a given logic, in this case based on the loaded view. (I've read through the threads on showing elements based on a Role membership as well).

I'm trying to replicating the layout shown here: [URL To Sample](http://startbootstrap.com/templates/modern-business/index.html). It has a bootstrap carousel and I like the placement extending the entire width but only showing on the Index (Home) page. Implementing this outside of the classic MVC structure is trivial.

With MVC we have the shared _Layout.cshtml and the container where views are loaded with ...

```
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

It seems the carousel needs either

- be placed on the _Layout page and hidden if the loaded view is not the Index page or
- be placed on the Index page and allowed to exceed the width of the container

I've tried what I've been able to find in threads but haven't been able to replicate this layout cleanly.  Can someone please give a bit of direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [stretch it with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625116/css-position-absolute-full-width-problem/6625410#6625410), or a cleaner solution could be to put it in its own (optional) section:

in _Layout:

```
@RenderSection("carousel", required: false)
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

in your front page/home (index) file:

```
@section carousel {
    // code for carousel
}
```

---

As commented by @Alex, if your home page is significantly different from the other pages, you can use a separate layout file. To do this, just set the "Layout" global string like this;

in your front page/home (index) file:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_FrontPageLayout.cshtml"; // to use a separate file
    Layout = null; // to not use a layout file
}
```

Comment: +1 for an optional section. You can also use a different layout or not use a layout for the index page altogether, if it's very different from the other pages.