# Simple Overlay for item in Flatlist is too slow

Tags: react-native

I have a simple overlay component that is rendered on top of certain items in a Flatlist. The list item component which is the parent component of the overlay sends down a dimensions object that lives on its state and gets updated onLayout. The overlay doesn't stretch quite fast enough when you go from portrait to landscape mode.

component: `<View style={style.container}>
        <View style={[style.overlay, dimensions()]} />
      </View>`

Any ideas how to make this respond faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve good results by using the solution from here: 
[Stretch Absolute Positioned element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625116/css-position-absolute-full-width-problem)