# Sticky header spans not across whole container width

Tags: css

I have a container with some huge content inside (wider and taller than the container).

For the content to be scrollable I added `overflow: auto` as a CSS property to the container; now I also want a header inside of the container with `position: sticky` and `top: 0`.

To prevent overlapping text when scrolling downwards the header gets a `background-color`.

Problem: the background of the header ends at the outer width of the container and does not take the full width of the scrollable area insider the container, you can see this when scrolling sideways.

Question: is there a way to make the header span the whole scroll width of the container?

```css
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: grey;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.content {
  width: 400px;
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    Test Text very looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
    eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat
    nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt
    ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie
    consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue
    nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
    exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
</div>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/n61o03zk/

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625116/css-position-absolute-and-full-width-problem

Comment: Why not just scroll the container you want to scroll, which is `.content`?

Comment: I want that (a) the header stays on top of the container when scrolling downwards and (b) the header scrolling together with the content when scrolling sideways. absolute positioning will not grant me (a) while only setting ```overflow: auto``` to the content will not yield (b).

Comment: But scrolling `.content` instead of `.container` will get you both.

Comment: Could you post an example? If I understand your comment correctly only my content would scroll sideways but not the header at the same time together with it?

Comment: There are a couple ways you can do it. You can either just take the header out of the container or you can remove the container's overflow style and put it on the content element instead, which may be more convoluted because you might want to have a second container to constrain the width and force a scroll. The exact method usually depends on what the rest of the content around your webpage looks like... for example, why did you choose a 300px by 300px container for content that is larger than that? Doing so is fine, but _why_ you are doing so may change what the ideal solution is.

Comment: The usecase is a huge form with multiple inputs in different columns. Each column has a heading which should always be visible when scrolling the page down but there can be more columns than fit in the width of the page. So 300x300 was just chosen as demonstration of a size constrained area.

Answer (score 2):

`display: grid` on the container will fix this

```css
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  display: grid;
}

.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: grey;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.content {
  width: 400px;
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    Test Text very looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
    eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat
    nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt
    ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie
    consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue
    nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
    exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

use CSS Grid to make the header span the full width of the scrollable container

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: grey;
  white-space: nowrap;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.content {
  width: 400px;
  background: teal;
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    Test Text very looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
    eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat
    nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt
    ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie
    consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue
    nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
    exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why are you repeating my answer?